# How to export report from ReportBuilder to FastReport?

Tags: reportbuilder, fastreport, delphi-10.1-berlin

Is there any easy way to export reports created in reportbuilder to fastreport? I have several reports and I would at least need the layout preserved in this conversion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add ConverterRB2FR unit in the uses list, add TfrxDesigner to project, use frxReport1.DesignReport; code to call run-time FR designer, open RB report template in the run-time FR Designer and save it as fr3

Comment: Thank you gpi. Works great!